# Is it legal for two or more users to use a Microsoft Windows computer at the same time?

Tags: software, licensing

I happened across a video called *7 Users on 1 PC! - but is it legal?* that is about an older product that allowed a computer with Windows XP or Windows server to be used by 7 different users at once through the use of some software and a special hardware device that added 6 additional video, audio, keyboard, and mouse devices to a single PC.

He said the product was supposed to be used with Windows server, so as not to violate the license concerning multiple concurrent users of Windows XP.

That got me thinking. Would playing a split screen video game with two game controllers and two users on the same PC be violating the license? Would having two monitors watched by two people playing two different videos violate the license?

I believe having multiple copies of Windows running as different virtual machine guests on one PC violates the license for Home versions of Windows 10. But does this limitation go as far back as DOS, Win95, or XP Home and Pro?

Comment: FWIW, Street Fighter IV was available on Microsoft's Games for Windows, which has a two-player mode, on the other hand, later versions of nComputing and Microsoft's own MultiPoint Services require Windows Server *and* one CAL for each user, so there's a line between two people using the same app and multiple people using different session, which your two monitors playing different video scenario straddles. Virtualization limitation exists at least as early as Windows XP since XP Mode has an explicit license allowing it to run on certain Windows 7 editions (*not* Home) without an extra license